# InfluxDB time storing

Tags: python, time, influxdb

I wanted to ask in what format does Python InfluxDB API return time?
Because it doesn't return it in timestamp, when I divide it from 100 I get about 2200 years, when I divide it from 1000 I get 2024 years and when I divide it from 10000, I get 1980 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `Influxdb` API returns `Timestamp` in `miliseconds`. But for Python Influxdb API is in clearly in `seconds`.

Which version of `InfluxDB` Python API are you using?

Comment: I accidentally was dividing the sequence number, not time

Answer (score 0):

here is a code to transform the weird influx time datatype to datetime once you have the data stored in csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1, inplace=True)
from datetime import datetime
datetime_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(df['time'])):
    datetime_list.append(datetime.strptime(df['time'][1], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
datetime_column = pd.Series(datetime_list,dtype='datetime64[ns]')
df.drop('time', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.insert(loc = 0, column='time',value=datetime_column,allow_duplicates=True)
```